# Error loading module 'Ninject.Web.Mvc.MvcModule' of type MvcModule

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, ninject, ninject.web.mvc

I am building an ASP.NET MVC5 web application, using Ninject.MVC5 for DI. I'm trying to move the NinjectWebCommon class into a separate class-library project. I was able to do this successfully by using the following code:

```
private static IKernel CreateKernel()
{
    var kernel = new StandardKernel();
    try
    {
        // Uncomment to move this file to a separate DLL
        kernel.Load("MyWebApp.dll");
        kernel.Bind<Func<IKernel>>().ToMethod(ctx => () => new Bootstrapper().Kernel);
        kernel.Bind<IHttpModule>().To<HttpApplicationInitializationHttpModule>();

        RegisterServices(kernel);
        return kernel;
    }
    catch
    {
        kernel.Dispose();
        throw;
    }
}
```

In the above code, `MyWebApp.dll` is the filename of the main web application assembly. This works, but requires me to hard-code a reference to the web application DLL. I read in the official documentation that the following could can be used to automatically load *all* DLLs in a solution that has been separated in this fashion:

```
kernel.Load(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies());
```

However, if I use this code instead of the hard-coded reference, I receive the following exception (caught and re-thrown at the `throw` line above):

```
An exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException' occurred in
MyWebApp.Infrastructure.dll and wasn't handled before a managed/native boundary

Additional information: Error loading module 'Ninject.Web.Mvc.MvcModule' of
type MvcModule
```

Can anyone provide some information on what is happening here, and how to prevent this exception from occurring while avoiding hardcoded references to other assemblies?

Comment: `AppDomain.CurrentDomain` contains only assemblies which were already loaded into domain - in general case, that is not all the DLLs in the \bin folder. If you can reference `MyWebApp.dll`, then you can just use `typeof(SomeClassInsideMyWebApp).Assembly`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you create your Kernel, you need to make sure that the setting `LoadExtensions` is set to **false**.

According to the documentation :

> LoadExtensions: *Gets or sets a value indicating whether the kernel
>   should automatically load extensions at startup.*

The following line:

```
var kernel = new StandardKernel();
```

... should become this:

```
var kernel = new StandardKernel(new NinjectSettings() { LoadExtensions = false });
```

Comment: This worked for me, but why does this work and when do you set this property to `true`?

Comment: Yeah .. why would be a really nice addition to this!!